# Label inset_axes scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to label the scatter markers in this plot by numbering them, but I do not know how to get the inset_axes coordinates to place the labels.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(10))

x = np.random.rand(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)
labels = [str(num+1) for num in range(len(x))]

axin2 = ax.inset_axes(
    [5, 7, 2.3, 2.3], transform=ax.transData)
axin2.scatter(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I am unsure what you want the output to look like. Please add more details or a drawing to demonstrate what you want the output to be.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have much experience with this type of graph, but I think I can use the coordinates of the scatter plot I have already set up and annotate it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(2021)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9))
ax.plot(range(10))

x = np.random.rand(5)
y = np.random.rand(5)
labels = [str(num+1) for num in range(len(x))]

axin2 = ax.inset_axes(
    [5, 7, 2.3, 2.3], transform=ax.transData)
axin2.scatter(x, y)

for i in range(len(x)):
    axin2.annotate(str(i), xy=(x[i]+0.02,y[i]))
inset = axin2.transData
# print(inset)
plt.show()
```

[image]